# Saying how is it that you know French

Tags: traduction

How would you say:
"How is it that you know French?"

Comment est-il que tu sais le français?

Merci à tous.

Answer (score 5):

An idiomatic, casual way would be:

> *Comment ça se fait que tu parles/comprends/lis le français ?*

One century ago, you might have heard :

> *Comment se fait-il que tu saches le français ?*

It would be still understood but this form is outdated or at least very literary.

If you insist to use *savoir*, that can be:

> *Comment ça se fait que tu sais parler français ?*

Comment: Merci. Vous n'ajoutez pas le verbe savoir dans ce context?

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: Simplement, et utilisable aujourd'hui :  "Comment se fait-il que tu parles/connaisses le Français" marche aussi.

Comment: Rectification on the use of "Comment se fait-il que...": this is still very much used in middle-to-higher social categories and formal contexts. Personally, I use it just as frequently as "Comment ça se fait", and I'm neither 100 years old nor speaking like Balzac :)